# How to import ultralytics to python3.9

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, python-3.9, yolov8

I installed python3.9 along with python3.6 on my Raspberry-pi. I also installed pip3.9 and ultralytics. Now  when I try importing ultralytics to python3.9, it gives me the following error: illegal instructions.
How can I fix this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRmLY.jpg)

I want to have ultralytics running so I can excute python files that includes ultralytics.

Answer (score 0):

I explained its reason on another post [Raspberry Pi 3B+ not work ultralytics yolov8. Error "illegal instruction"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909348/raspberry-pi-3b-not-work-ultralytics-yolov8-error-illegal-instruction) But basically downgrade required libraries

Make sure that pip installes them for python3.9

```
pip3 install torch==1.12.0

pip3 install torchvision==0.13.0
```

if any problems occur about torch, check here for compatibility of versions. https://pypi.org/project/torchvision/

I ran it on Raspberry Pi 4